# Луна и солнце являются предметами?

Tags: лингвистика

"Солнце и луна, ветер и волна, вода и огонь." Какие слова являются предметами? Предметы: ветер, волна, вода, огонь. А луна и солнце?

Comment: "Солнце и луна, ветер и волна, вода и огонь." Какие слова являются предметами?-  вопрос взят из рабочей тетради по русскому языку для 1 класса( программа "Школа России"- Е.М. Тихомирова)

Answer (score 1):

ПРЕДМЕТ - нечто материальное, отдельное и оформленное, воспринимаемое зрительно (возможно также на вкус, на ощупь, обонянием).
Следуя этому определению, **воду** и **огонь** нельзя назвать предметами, потому что отсутствуют признаки "отдельное" и "оформленное". **Волна**, на мой взгляд, может быть названа предметом, потому что наличествует признак отдельности (наряду с материальностью и воспринимаемостью), признак оформленности несколько размыт, но, скажем, на картинах и фотографиях (остановись, мгновенье!) он есть. **Ветер** - материальное, воспринимаемое, но не отдельное и не оформленное. Так что это тоже не предмет, а явление. А **солнце** и **луна** - небесные светила, полностью соответствующие определению слова *предмет*.

Answer (score 1):

Смею заметить, что **слова** не могут быть **предметами**. В лучшем случае - называть их.

А в отношении пречисленных слов: **в полной мере ни одно из них с предметом не соотносится**. Хотя тут зависит, конечно, от определения. Насколько знаю, филология предметами как таковыми не занимается. Поэтому определение можно выбирать подходящее.

Я не совсем понимаю, что такое "признак оформленности" (из предыдущего ответа), а предмет бы определил согласно вики-словарю: "отдельное материальное неодушевлённое тело, объект, вещь, как правило, не очень больших размеров". Отсюда и все выводы.

Но при чем тут русский язык?